# LibGDX: Scene2D Stage wont react on multiplexer input

Tags: libgdx

I've got an inputMultiplexer. I want to register about two or three "systems" as processors. The classes which implementing InputProcessor get registerd by me like `inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(this);`. This works fine.

Unfortunately the stage which got registered very similarly

```
stage = new Stage();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
```

won't work. This means it won't act on any kind of user input. The strange thing is that if I don't add the other systems as processors - so the stage is the only one - it works very fine. Right now the stage gets registered as the second processor. I don't know if this could be the problem.

Do you have any idea what the problem here is?